# ldapsearch with partial numeric filter

Tags: string, search, ldap, comparison, ldap-query

Sun Directory Server here.  I can easily use an asterisk in a filter for fields that are definitely strings to, for example, get the list of uids that all start with a certain letter.  However, I cannot use the same syntax to get, for example, all uidNumbers starting with a certain number.

Here are some descriptions of the output I get for various commands.

**Returns all uids that start with the letter b**:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=Directory Manager" -h server -b "ou=people,dc=test,dc=com" "uid=b*" "uid"
```

**Returns no values:**

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=Directory Manager" -h server -b "ou=people,dc=test,dc=com" "uidNumber=446*" "uidNumber"
```

**However, this WILL return anything with 446 anywhere in the uidNumber:**

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=Directory Manager" -h server -b "ou=people,dc=test,dc=com" "uidNumber=*446*" "uidNumber"
```

I'm looking for any uidNumbers that *START* with 446.  With the above, it gives me the ones that start with 446, but it also gives me ones like "3446".

I must be overlooking some small detail, as this doesn't seem like it should be that complicated.

Comment: In my servers, `uidnumber` does not have a substring matching rule. The last two examples use substring filters, hence they won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. `uidNumber` is specified to use the `integerMatch` matching rule. "The rule evaluates to TRUE if and only if the attribute value and the assertion value are the same integer value." [RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-4.2.19)

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my question: *446* gives me anything with 446.  446* however gives me NO results (when I would expect that it would give me any that start with 446).

Comment: Just experimenting, I found that (&(uidNumber>=4460)(uidNumber<=4469)) accomplishes my goal.  bleh, I guess that works...

Comment: Consider informing the LDAP administrators that an ordering index for `uidNumber` might be necessary since you're using ordering assertions (`>=`, etc).